# Is there a way to exclude a specific package from hoisting in PNPM?

Tags: pnpm

YARN has a `nohoist` option to prevent from hoisting a specific package.

Does PNPM have an equivalent option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of pnpm v6.7, pnpm does not allow to exclude from hoisting. With pnpm you define which package should be hoisted not which should not be hoisted.

To hoist nothing, you may set `hoist=false` in `.npmrc`.

To hoist only the babel packages, you may set `hoist-pattern[]=@babel/*`

Comment: Hi, this doesn't really answer the question, how do you prevent hoisting for one package? For instance Apollo need a postinstall fix to work with ESM and should not be hoisted in my app

Comment: as I said, it is not possible. There is no such feature in pnpm currently. You can only disable hoisting or list the packages you want to hoist. Excluding is not possible. There is a feature request for it: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5272

Comment: As of pnpm v7.12 allows excluding packages by adding an exclamation mark like `hoist-pattern[]=!@types/node`

Answer (score 7):

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67864697/7869175) is outdated.

Since `v7.12.0`, you can exclude patterns from hoisting using `!`.

For example:

`.npmrc`

```bash
hoist-pattern[]=*types*
hoist-pattern[]=!@types/react
```

Via the docs: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#hoist-pattern

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I include `@web/test-runner-playwright` in `devDependencies` and do not want to hoist its transitive dependency, `playwright-core`. So, I add `hoist-pattern[] = !playwright-core` and run `pnpm i`. `playwright-core` is still under `node_modules/.pnpm`.